# cannot open file 'LIBC.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I changed a workspace developed in VC 6.0 to VS 2008. When I tried to build the workspace I am getting the following error message. How can I correct the problem?

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'LIBC.lib'
```

I am getting the following messages when I ignored libc.lib

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class CIHoTSimEngine * __cdecl CreateHoTSimEngine(void)" (__imp_?CreateHoTSimEngine@@YAPAVCIHoTSimEngine@@XZ) referenced in function "private: int __thiscall CHoTSimV2Doc::Init(void)" (?Init@CHoTSimV2Doc@@AAEHXZ)   HoTSimV2Doc.obj HoTSimV2
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class CIFABConnect * __cdecl CreateFabConnectServer(void)" (__imp_?CreateFabConnectServer@@YAPAVCIFABConnect@@XZ) referenced in function "private: int __thiscall CHoTSimV2Doc::Init(void)" (?Init@CHoTSimV2Doc@@AAEHXZ)   HoTSimV2Doc.obj HoTSimV2
Error   3   fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals D:\Projects\AsWorxSim\Bin\Release\HoTSim2.0.exe 1   HoTSimV2
```

Answer (score 16):

Project Property -> Configuation Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Ignore Specific Library

Ignore the LIBC.LIB

Edit: I think once you remove the LIBC.lib as mentioned above, you are moving ahead with your linking and getting errors which exist in your app. You should try to look in these errors now. Think about it, if libc.lib was missing in the first place then how could it provide any linkage which seems to have appeared after you ignored it.

Comment: I got a few link errors when I removed libc.lib. The link errors are added to my original post

Comment: @Maanu: Try running `vsvars32.bat` to setup the enviornment & also don't ignore Libc.lib.

Comment: It is still not working. I executed the batch file and restarted visual studio

Answer (score 1):

Command line option:

```
cl source.cpp /link /NODEFAULTLIB:LIBC.LIB
```

Answer (score 0):

look here:
[Discussion about libc on microsoft forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/22f1d8b8-9abb-4a32-b5f7-565dc396e0aa) that's for vs2005 but for 2008 it is the same...

Answer (score 0):

You need to "Rebuild All", to make sure you don't have any .obj files from VC6 hanging around.